# how to add tabreorderer on Tabpanel in MVC Ext.Net

Tags: ext.net

I have a TabPanel and some tabs on it. How can I rearrange them forward or backward using tabreorderer plugin or something else. I want to do this in Ext.NET MVC. A small Sample code is shown below:

> Html.X().TabPanel()
>
> ```
> .ID("TabPanel1")
> .AutoScroll(true)
> .Flex(8)
> //.BodyPadding(10)
> .MinTabWidth(140)
> .Items(
>     Html.X().Panel()
>         .Title("Dashboard")
>         .LayoutConfig(new FitLayoutConfig { DefaultMargins = "0" })
>         .BodyStyle("background:White !important;")
>         .StyleSpec("border:3px solid White; !important")
>         //.BodyPadding(5)
>         .ContextMenuID("contextMenuPopup")
>         .AutoScroll(true)
>         .Items(
>             Html.X().Panel()
>                 .Layout(LayoutType.VBox)
>                 .Border(false)
>                 .LayoutConfig(new VBoxLayoutConfig { Align = VBoxAlign.Stretch })
>                 .Items(
>                     Html.X().Panel()
>                         //.Flex(1)
>                         .Height(35)
>                         .Layout(LayoutType.Fit)
>                         .Border(false)
> ```

In this code I have one panel i.e. Dashboard. Similarly I am adding some more panels but dynamically on click of menu items. SO can anybody know how to use 'tabreorderer' plugin here. As I tried to add the plugin on Tabpanel direcly using below code:

> .Plugins(Html.X().TabReorderer())

but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the `TabReorderer` Plugin to the Plugins Collection.

**Examples**

```
.Plugins(plugins => {
    plugins.Add(Html.X().TabReorderer());
})
```

Hope this helps.